# Simplifying $\frac{\Gamma\left(x\right)^{2}}{\Gamma\left(x-\sqrt{2}\right)\Gamma\left(x+\sqrt{2}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, gamma-function

Is there any way to simplify the following expression, $$\frac{\Gamma\left(x\right)^{2}}{\Gamma\left(x-\sqrt{2}\right)\Gamma\left(x+\sqrt{2}\right)}$$
This actually prompts me to ask whether we have any identity for 
$$\Gamma\left(a-b\right)\Gamma\left(a+b\right)?$$
I know there's an identity for $\Gamma\left(a-b\right)\Gamma\left(b-a\right)$ via the reflection-formula. The first equation can be expressed as in terms of the Beta function, but I don't want to unnecessarily bring in that.
So will this stay as it is or can it be a little bit more simplified? Also $x\in\mathbb R$

Some elementary simplifications I could find is,
$$-2\operatorname{sinc}\left(\pi\sqrt{2}\right)\cdot \operatorname{B}\left(x,\sqrt{2}\right)\operatorname{B}\left(x,-\sqrt{2}\right)$$

Well I guess that's it.

Comment: Writing it as $\frac{\operatorname{B}\left(x,\,x\right)}{\operatorname{B}\left(x-\sqrt{2},\,x+\sqrt{2}\right)}$ seems our only other option. We only have neat expressions for $\Gamma(y)\Gamma(n-y)$ if $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have much choice for rewriting this expression.

However, you can have excellent *approximation* using series or Padé approximants even for small values of $x$. For example
$$\frac{\Gamma (x)^2}{\Gamma (x-a) \Gamma (x+a)}=1-\frac{a^2}{x}+\frac{a^2 \left(a^2-1\right)}{2 x^2}-\frac{a^2
   \left(a^2-1\right)^2}{6 x^3}+\frac{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right)^2}{24 x^4}-\frac{a^2 (a^2-1)^2 (a^4+2a^2-4)  }{120  x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$

For $a=\sqrt 2$, this gives an absolute error of $4.87 \times 10^{-6}$ for $x=4$ (relative error : $8.72\times 10^{-4}$%)

**Edit**

Writing 
$$\frac{\Gamma (x)^2}{\Gamma (x-a) \Gamma (x+a)}=1-\frac{a^2}{x}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {c_n}{x^n}$$ let
$$d_n=(-1)^n {n!}\,c_n$$ the $d_n$'s are polynomials  in $a^2$.

There is a different pattern depending on the parity.

- For odd values of $n$, $d_n=(a^2-1)^2\, a^2\, P_n(a^2)$
- For even values of $n$, $d_n=(a^2-1)^2\, a^4\, Q_n(a^2)$

Let $b=a^2$ and here are the first terms
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(b) \\
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & b^2+2 b-4 \\
 7 & b^4+16 b^3-11 b^2-96 b+120 \\
 9 & b^6+50 b^5+393 b^4-1660 b^3-1520 b^2+11808 b-12096 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & Q_n(b) \\
 4 & 1 \\
 6 & b^2+7 b-14 \\
 8 & b^4+30 b^3+73 b^2-600 b+736 \\
 10 & b^6+77 b^5+1239 b^4-1129 b^3-30716 b^2+104832 b-104544
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using all the above for $a=\sqrt 2$ and $x=4$, the absolute error is $2.40\times 10^{-10}$ (relative error : $4.31\times 10^{-8}$%).

Now, what are these polynomials ? *"That is the question !"*.

**Edit**

It seems that it could be better to consider the reciprocal of the expression
$$\frac{\Gamma (x-a) \Gamma (x+a)}{\Gamma (x)^2}=1+\frac{a^2}{x}+\frac{a^2 \left(a^2+1\right)}{2 x^2}+\frac{a^2 \left(a^4+4 a^2+1\right)}{6 x^3}+\frac{a^4 \left(a^4+10 a^2+13\right)}{24 x^4}+\frac{a^2 \left(a^8+20 a^6+73 a^4+30 a^2-4\right)}{120 x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$
Writing 
$$\frac{\Gamma (x-a) \Gamma (x+a)}{\Gamma (x)^2}=+\frac{a^2}{x}+\frac{a^2 \left(a^2+1\right)}{2 x^2}+\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac {c_n}{x^n}$$ let
$$d_n={n!}\,c_n$$ the $d_n$'s are polynomials  in $a^2$.

There is a different pattern depending on the parity.

- For odd values of $n$, $d_n= a^2\, P_n(a^2)$
- For even values of $n$, $d_n= a^4\, Q_n(a^2)$

Let $b=a^2$ and here are the first terms
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(b) \\
 3 & b^2+4 b+1 \\
 5 & b^4+20 b^3+73 b^2+30 b-4 \\
 7 & b^6+56 b^5+798 b^4+3008 b^3+1561 b^2-504 b+120 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & Q_n(b) \\
 4 & b^2+10 b+13 \\
 6 & b^4+35 b^3+273 b^2+425 b-14 \\
 8 & b^6+84 b^5+1974 b^4+14572 b^3+25809 b^2-2856 b+736 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: How is this derived and is there a general formula for the terms?

Comment: @martycohen. This is just Stirling approximation for large $x$. There is *probably* a pattern. I am still working the problem. If I find *anything*, I shall post and let you know. Cheers.

Comment: @martycohen. I found a few minor things. Any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: In terms of Pochhammer symbols and Nörlund polynomials, it is $$
c_n  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n ( - 1)^k \frac{(a)_k (a)_k }{k!}\binom{n - 1}{n - k} B_{n - k}^{( - k - 1)} (a - 1).
$$ I may supply the proof later.

Comment: @Gary. This would be great ! Thanks for the result.

Comment: Apply http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E19 with $z=x$, $a=b=0$, $c=a$. Divide both sides by $\Gamma(x-a)$. On the right-hand side move it inside the sum. Now, under the sum, use http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E13 for each gamma-ratio and re-arrange the expansion in powers of $1/x$.